# Ошибка генерирования и вывода букв

Tags: java, android

Друзья, встал в тупик.
в idea все нормально, в AndroidStudio в эмуляторе и на телефоне (кидаю apk)  возникает ошибка.
1. Выбираю рандомно слово, бью его на буквы
2. Перемешиваю буквы
3. Буквы выводятся каждая на свою кнопку (и тестово в поле)

На п.3 возникает проблема - появляется пустая буква, призрак. Убрал все лишнее, оставил только саму суть. Не могу понять в чем дело.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button start;
    TextView text;
    String[] OriginalWord; //бавзовое слово
    String[] MixedleWord; //смешение

    public void RandomGen() {
        String[] stringArr = {"сапфир", "ураган", "разбор", "дракон"};
        int oneLength = stringArr.length;
        int rand1 = (int) (Math.random() * oneLength);
        String RandomWord = stringArr[rand1];
        this.OriginalWord = RandomWord.split("");//разбив по буквам

        String[] Literals = Arrays.copyOf(OriginalWord, OriginalWord.length);
        List<String> shuffle = Arrays.asList(Literals);
        Collections.shuffle(shuffle);
        shuffle.toArray(Literals);
        this.MixedleWord = Literals;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        RandomGen();
        text.setText(Arrays.toString(MixedleWord));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
split("")
```

Возвращает все символы строки, а так же две пустых строки.

Отфильтруйте массив так, чтобы он не содержал пустых строк и все заработает.

Comment: Есть какой-то готовый метод, как лучше всего сделать  Или может какие-то альтернативные варианты есть? Просто интересно - почему в idea(swing) проблем не было с этим?

Comment: @Freijer возможно, там (в Swing) есть какая-то обработка пустых строк. Для Java Array удобного фильтра не помню, можно просто создать новый и в цикле по всем элементам добавить в него непустые строки из старого.